# Click event only fires when element is placed in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I've got a single-page app UI with a custom navigation script. The script works perfectly in a minimally styled test page, but when I bring it into the actual app UI, it starts getting wonky and the click events are not firing consistently the way that I'd expect them to.

I have click events bound to each of the links, but the events only seem to fire when the element is placed in the header.

### The HTML

```
<header>
    <a data-role="navigation" data-target-view="mainView">Home</a>
    <a data-role="navigation" data-target-view="settings">Settings</a>
    <a id="headerLink" data-role="navigation" data-target-view="detailsView">Details</a>
</header>

<section data-role="page">
    <section id="mainView" data-role="view">
        <section class="pageContent">

        </section>

        <footer class="pageFooter">
            <a id="footerLink" data-role="navigation" data-target-view="detailsView">Details</a>
        </footer>
    </section>

    <section id="detailsView" data-role="view">
        <section class="pageContent">

        </section>

        <footer class="pageFooter">

        </footer>
    </section>

    <section id="settings" data-role="view">
        <section class="pageContent">

        </section>

        <footer class="pageFooter">

        </footer>
    </section>
</section>
```

### Handler Registration

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-role='navigation']")
        .unbind("click.cgt_pathfinder")
        .bind("click.cgt_pathfinder",function(event){
            alert("Triggered");
        });
});
```

I've stripped out the actual navigation logic just to make this easier to follow.

### The Issue

When I load the page, I've got a breakpoint set on my handler registration, and I can see all the elements retrieved by `$("[data-role='navigation']")`. I see 4 elements: The three links in the `<header>`, and the one solitary link in the `.pageFooter` section of `#mainView`.

You'll notice that (save for the ID attribute and their location on the page), `#headerLink` and `#footerLink` are identical.

When I click `#footerLink`, nothing happens. I know the element was picked up when I registered my event handler, so it *should* issue the "Triggered" alert message, but it doesn't.

I've also tried moving `#footerLink` around the document (pulling it up one layer at a time and testing at each stop. The event did not fire until the link was in the `<header>`

When I click `#headerLink`, the event fires exactly as expected. In this example, I receive the "Triggered" message, and in the actual app, I see a successful navigation event.

So, the question is: "What am I missing?" There's *something* different about `#footerLink` that's preventing the event from firing, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Could you provide minimal code

Comment: I provided all the code necessary to recreate the issue. In fact, I edited my HTML/JS files to match this exact content, and I saw the same result as described in the issue

Comment: have you checked by putting your event registration code in `$(document).ready(function(){ });` block?

Comment: @vijayP It actually is in a `ready()` block. I didn't bother including that since it seemed obvious when dealing with handler registration. Sorry for the confusion. --Updated the question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly typo and unbalanced tag

```
    <section data-role="page">
        <section id="mainView data-role="view">  // No (") for id
            <section class="pageContent">

            </section>
```

Near bottom of markup

```
        </settings>   // No opening tag for settings
    </section>
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huygd6s6/3/)

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos, but that does not appear to address the issue.

Comment: @Mike can you please check the jsfiddle link.It seems working

Comment: It definitely is working there. I even wrote it myself from scratch in a new fiddle just as a sanity check, but it's also definitely not working in the running app.

Comment: It is. I stripped things down so that the only remaining difference between the working JS fiddle and my local app was a CSS file. Then I took away the CSS file, and it still doesn't work locally. I know I'm missing something, and as these things go, it's going to be embarrassingly obvious when I (or anyone else) finally find what it is

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your case. But it is working fine for me.

Please replace your jQuery function with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-role='navigation']").unbind("click.cgt_pathfinder").bind("click.cgt_pathfinder",function(event){
        alert("Triggered = "+$(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Appending the text only proves which element has been clicked, but the `#footerLink` never reaches that line to begin with, so this doesn't really address the issue. That said, I've seen for myself that my markup as posted here works in JS fiddle, which further confuses me, because it definitely does not on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code dynamically update the `#footerLink` element ?

If this element gets added to the page by your code (e.g : through a `$('.pageFooter').append(html)`), you will need to bind back the click action to this new element.

---

Is there any other code (yours or some plugin's) which could alter the `click` event handlers in your page, but not in your header ?

Comment: Nope, and nope. There will be a good chunk of content added dynamically, but the buttons are static elements

Comment: @Mike : what is the list of js librairies included in your page ?

Comment: Currently, it's the latest version of jQuery and my custom navigation script (i've diabled everything else to see if there was a conflict). I've also pieced together that the event handler is not always assigned (despite the element appearing in the jQuery object), so I'm confident the bug is in my custom script, but there's so much about that script that's in flux that I hesitate to share it. I'm rewriting a few pieces of it now to organize it a little better. Once that's finished, I'll share since it seems that has to be where the problem is.

Comment: Try inspecting what event handlers are bound. In Firefox, you can install the FireQuery addon, which will add in your Inspector view the list of event handlers bound to each DOM node. This + breakpoints in your code to see what is registered and what is not at various points during the execution of your script.